# Databricks notebook how to add a title to a cell

Tags: databricks

How to add title to the cell itself like this (The tile and the code are in the same command cell):

[image]

Instead of putting it in a separate cell like this (The tile and the code are in different command cells):
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you want [image] which will give you [image]